# Maximally touching toruses

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics

7 identical cylinders can mutually touch each other, if sufficiently long.  For cylinders of different sizes, 8 can touch each other.

What is the maximal number of mutually touching toruses?  I suppose it might be 7, using the 7 cylinder solution. But perhaps there is something more clever.

Comment: Can you give references for the cylinder case, please

Comment: I can see how 6 cylinders (and no more) can be arranged to touch a single given cylinder. Is that what "mutually touching" means?

Comment: Surely this will depend critically on the geometry of the tori? Presuming you mean a torus created as a surface of revolution of a circle, there's a single parameter to define how fat or thin it is. I'd expect the answer for a very thin torus to be the same as cylinders, but much fewer for a very fat torus (my intuition would suggest 4).

Answer (score 4):

Just to answer the comment-question by "bubba" with a picture:

   [image: 7Cylinders]
<sub>(Image from [http://www.mathpuzzle.com/](http://www.mathpuzzle.com/Solution.htm))</sub>

And see the paper "On the Number of Mutually Touching Cylinders" by K. Bezdek:
*Combinatorial and Computational Geometry* 52 (2005): 121-127.
([PDF download](http://library.msri.org/books/Book52/files/07bezd.pdf))

**Update.**
The cylinder problem has just been solved for $\infty$-cylinders
(Aug 2103):
"Seven mutually touching infinite cylinders."
Sándor Bozóki, Tsung-Lin Lee, Lajos Rónyai. [arXiv:1308.5164](http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.5164):

   [image: Fig2]

Comment: Yep, I know about that one.  mathpuzzle.com is my site.

Comment: I didn't realize that was your site! :-) In any case, that was not for you, but for others. Great question, Ed!